# In a Zend Framework 2 Module.php the getFilterConfig() method is never called

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules, zend-filter

I have a Generic module in my Zend Framework 2 application with some filters in it.

For my entity I created a filter class with an *InputFilterAwareInterface*:

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory     = new InputFactory();
        $inputFilter->add(
            $factory->createInput(
                array(
                    'name'     => 'desc',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'myfilter'),
                    ),
                )
            )
        );

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }
    return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

To load *myfilter* I implemented the Generic's Module.php with a *FilterProviderInterface*:

```
public function getFilterConfig()
{
    // Breakpoint at next line
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'myfilter' => function($sl) {
                $myfilter = $sl->getServiceLocator()->get('myfilterfactory');
                return new Filter\Filter\MyFilter($myfilter);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

When I run the application an exception is thrown:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
Zend\Filter\FilterPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for myfilter
```

I ran the debugger and realized that the *getFilterConfig()* method is never called, because the breakpoint is not triggered.

What do I need to insert in my code to get the filter config loaded?

EDIT:

The code is executed but the debugger does not stop at the breakpoint. When I insert an additional statement and set the breakpoint to this, the execution stops.

In a controller I do the following

```
$serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
$filterManager = $serviceManager->get('FilterManager');
```

and within the filter manager I have *myfilter* in the *factories* array. But still I get the exception.

How does the Zend\InputFilter\Factory (as InputFactory) know about the filter factory?

Comment: did you have a factory like this public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'myfilterfactory' => 'Application\Filter\MyFilterFactory', 
                
            ));
    }

Comment: Yes I have, the problem seems to be that the method is not executed and not an error within the method.

Comment: I've done a test in my module and it works. Try to post more code.

Comment: Filter\Filter\MyFilter($myfilter); do you have amodule called Filter ? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html your code doesn't call $mymodelentities->getInputFilter()

Comment: I have a Generic module as I need the filter in more modules. The path is Generic/src/Filter/Filter. Double filter comes from the filter implementations and the factories that should be in a separate folder Generic/src/Filter/Factory. Maybe I should clean this. Concerning the getInputFilter(): This is called, because in my question I only wrote the part of the code concerning my problem. There are other filters in it that are executed correctly. I have a separate filter class in parallel of my entity. But this works for Zend Framework's filters. So I think this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out what went wrong and how to solve this:

Within the Zend\InputFilter\Factory that I used as InputFactory a *defaultFilterChain* is created from scratch which generates a new *FilterPluginManager* that does not get the service manager's filters.

To solve this I insert a factory for the entity filter into the service manager which injects a *defaultFilterChain* with filters of the service manager:

```
'EntityFilter' => function($sm) {
    $filterManager = $sm->get('FilterManager');            
    $filterChain = new FilterChain;
    $filterChain->setPluginManager($filterManager);
    return new EntityFilter($filterChain);
 }
```

Within the *getInputFilter* method of the filter class *EntityFilter* this is inserted into the *InputFactory*:

```
$factory = new InputFactory();
$factory->setDefaultFilterChain($this->defaultFilterChain);
```

Now the *InputFactory* can also use these filters of the service manager's filter manager that includes *myfilter*.

Comment: You can use a service factory for this purpose. Code and instructions here: https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/8418700

Comment: +1 Nice one, I've had the same issue where the factory wasn't being found despite implementing `FilterProviderInterface`. You just saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem most certainly is within your call to `$sl->....->get('myfilterfactory')`

Try using `die("foo");` before that call and you'll see that `die()` is executed. And then your code appears to be a little unclean or rather you're unknown of how to do it better maybe.

You are using a factory, so why not use a real factory?

```
'factories' => array(
    'myfilter' => 'YourNamespace\Filter\MyFilterFactory'
)

class MyFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface 
    public function createService($sl)
        $filterClass = new MyFilter();
        $filterClass->setDependency(
            $sl->getServiceLocator()->get('someDependency')
        )
        return $filterClass
```

Comment: I tried it with the _die_ statement, but the application is not killed and I still get the exception.

Comment: You sure the Module is loaded? ^^ You could also check the merged configuration in your controller or anywhere and do a debug for `$serviceLocator->get('config')`, just to see if it's really there